# Javascript: Get the innerHTML of a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am retrieving some information from an xml file ( movie information ) and I am creating dynamically some DOM elements according to each movie. I want, when I click on the **test** element, to get the value of the title of the movie. Right now, no matter which movie I click, it gets the title of the last movie that was introduced.

How can I get the title of each individual movie when I click on that div and not the last one introduced by the for-loop?

```
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie");
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            var titlu =  x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var description = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            var descriere = document.createElement('div');
            descriere.className='expandedDescriere';
            descriere.innerHTML = description;

            var titlediv = document.createElement('div');       
            titlediv.className = 'title';       
            titlediv.id='title';        
            titlediv.innerHTML = title;

            var test=document.createElement('div');
            test.className='test';
            test.onclick= function(){
                          var filmName= test.previousSibling.innerHTML;
                          alert(filmName);
                          }
            placeholder.appendChild(titlediv);
            placeholder.appendChild(test);
            placeholder.appendChild(descriere);
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be in the function you assigned to `onclick`:

```
test.onclick= function(){
                      var filmName= test.previousSibling.innerHTML; // <===
                      alert(filmName);
              }
```

the marked line should be `var filmName= this.previousSibling.innerHTML;`

My guess is that the `var test` is [hoisted](http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/) out of the `for` loop, meaning that when the loop finished, all the `onclick` function are referencing the same `test` variable which is the last element you created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to reference the clicked element:

```
test.onclick = function() {
                 var filmName = this.previousSibling.innerHTML;
                 alert(filmName);
               };
```

Comment: Thank you :) it worked, but I'll accept the answer below. It's the same one but I think the points from a correct answer will help him more than you.